# Copy files in folders with different names

Tags: python

I need to copy files from the folder called shape, but this folder is inside another folder that has different names.

For example I have 1000 folders all with different names, but within each of them I have a folder called shape, and I want to make a script in python that automatically copies all the files of that shape folder that is inside that folder that changes name and paste it into another directory that will always be the same.

txs in advance.

Comment: Do you need to do it in Python? Wouldn't be easier to use just shell commands?. Something like `mv */shape/* dest/` would be ok?

Comment: `os.rename()`, `copyfile(src, dst)`, `glob()` `os.remove()`.  There

Comment: To follow up on @fernand0, to 'Pythonize' what he said, just run `p = subprocess.Popen("mv */shape/* dest/".split(),cwd="my/source/directory")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: A much simpler way, inspired by a comment from @fernand0, is to run:

```
import subprocess

root_dir = "/Users/krekto/lots_of_folders/"
destination = "/Users/krekto/my_destination/"

cmd = "mv */shape/* {}".format(destination)   
p = subprocess.call(cmd.split(),cwd=root_dir,shell=True)
```

I have not been able to test this, but it should do what you need it to.

```
import os
import shutil

# Set up directory you want to copy from and to
root_dir = "/Users/krekto/lots_of_folders/"
destination = "/Users/krekto/my_destination/"

# Get the list of all directories in root_dir
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir, topdown=True):
   dir_list = dirs
   break

# Iterate over this list and see if 'shape/' exists
for dir in dir_list:

   sub_dir = os.listdir(dir) # List of all contents in dir

   # Iterate over contents and see if 'shape/' is present
   for d in sub_dir:

       # If so, copy all files and directories from it
       if d.lower() == 'shape':
          shape_dir = os.path.join(root_dir,dir,d)
          for f in os.list(shape_dir):
              shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(shape_dir,f),os.path.join(destination, f))
```